# Why is a property hiding Inherited function with same name?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, properties

I have a class `Foo` with a function `myName` in it.
Class `bar` Inherits from `Foo` and have a Property that is also called `myName`

I figured this should be OK since:

1. The [property will compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235304.aspx) to `get_myName()` (so there would not be a collision with `Foo::myName(int,int)`)
2. `Foo::myName` has arguments while, obviously, the property does not (again, no colision).

Yet I still get the warning:

```
'Bar.myName' hides inherited member 'Foo.myName(int, int)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
```

**Example Code:**

```
public class Foo
{
    public int myName(int a, int b)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

class Bar: Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;

    int myName
    {
        get
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, If I add to `bar` the function:

```
int get_myName() 
{
    return a+b;
}
```

As expected, I get an error about the function previously declared.
So what is happening here? Is the property not allowing me to use ALL overloads of `myName` in addition to `get_myName()`?

Comment: Can I ask why you have a method name the same as a property? Normally if there is any logic is involved with the return type your better off with a method, else property

Comment: @Sayse The parent class is more general, and it needs the arguments to decide what the result would be. The derived class is much more specific and the arguments are fixed. All the property does is get{base.myName(this.a, this.b);}. So as can you see the functinality is the same. The property is just for easier coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 10.3.3 of the C# spec contains:

> A derived class can **hide** inherited members by declaring new members with the same name or signature.

It doesn't say anything about the two members having to be the same kind of member. Note that even though one is a property and one is a method, there are still cases where they could be confused:

- The property could be of a delegate type, e.g. `Action<int, int>` in which case `PropertyName(10, 10)` would be valid.
- In some places where you use the property name, you could be trying to perform a method group conversion, so they'd both be valid.

Within the same class, we run into the rules of section 10.3:

> - The names of constants, fields, properties, events, or types must differ from the names of all other members declared in the same class.
> - The name of a method must differ from the names of all other nonmethods declared in the same class. [...]

The fact that you can't declare a method called `get_myName` is mentioned in section 10.3.9.1, as noted in comments.

Comment: The spec addresses `get_myName` in "10.3.9.1 Member names reserved for properties: For a property P (§10.7) of type T, the following signatures are reserved: `T get_P();` `void set_P(T value);` Both signatures are reserved, even if the property is read-only or write-only."

Answer (score 0):

We don't even need inheritance in the picture - you can't have "overloads" between a property and a method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    void DoStuff(int i,int j)
    {

    }

    int DoStuff { get { return 10; } }
}
```

Produces:

> error CS0102: The type 'ConsoleApplication4.Program' already contains a definition for 'DoStuff'