# I am a newbie creating an API using C#, encountered error "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Warning CS0108"

Tags: c#, api, warnings

I am encountering this same error on the following fields:

```
public string txnumber { get; set; }
public string qnumber { get; set; }
public string accountnumber { get; set; }
public decimal amount { get; set; }
public string emailaddress { get; set; }
```

this is defined in the class Txn.cs.

The error text for all the variables is:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Warning CS0108 'ReadTxn.txnumber' hides inherited member 'Txn.txnumber'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. QAny
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CS0108  'ReadTxn.txnumber' hides inherited member 'Txn.txnumber'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.   QAny    C:\Users\user\source\repos\QAny\QAny\Models\Txn.cs  37

Active Warning  CS0108  'ReadTxn.qnumber' hides inherited member 'Txn.qnumber'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. QAny    C:\Users\user\source\repos\QAny\QAny\Models\Txn.cs  38

Active Warning  CS0108  'ReadTxn.accountnumber' hides inherited member 'Txn.accountnumber'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. QAny    C:\Users\user\source\repos\QAny\QAny\Models\Txn.cs  39

Active Warning  CS0108  'ReadTxn.amount' hides inherited member 'Txn.amount'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.   QAny    C:\Users\user\source\repos\QAny\QAny\Models\Txn.cs  40

Active Warning  CS0108  'ReadTxn.emailaddress' hides inherited member 'Txn.emailaddress'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.   QAny    C:\Users\user\source\repos\QAny\QAny\Models\Txn.cs  41

========
here is the Txn.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace QAny.Models
{
    public class Txn
    {
        // define all the proeperties of the table with get and set
        public string txnumber { get; set; }
        public string qnumber { get; set; }
        public string accountnumber { get; set; }
        public decimal amount { get; set; }
        public string emailaddress { get; set; }

    }

    // will create a class to create an object of txn class

    public class createTxn : Txn
    {

    }

    public class ReadTxn : Txn
    {
        public ReadTxn(System.Data.DataRow row)
        {
            txnumber = row["txnumber"].ToString();
            qnumber = row["qnumber"].ToString();
            accountnumber = row["accountnumber"].ToString();
            amount = Convert.ToDecimal(row["amount"]);
            emailaddress = row["emailaddress"].ToString();
        }

        public string txnumber { get; set; }
        public string qnumber { get; set; }
        public string accountnumber { get; set; }
        public decimal amount { get; set; }
        public string emailaddress { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: "hides inherited member", Show the class declaration and the parent class.. [Compiler Warning (level 2) CS0108](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108). Note that the compiler tryed to give that information 6 times just in the quoted error message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a property hiding Inherited function with same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986680/why-is-a-property-hiding-inherited-function-with-same-name)

Comment: And [Why do I get warning CS0108 about a property hiding a method from a base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299497/why-do-i-get-warning-cs0108-about-a-property-hiding-a-method-from-a-base-class)

Answer (score 1):

Messages you are seeing indicate that class `ReadTxn` derives from class `Txn` which already contains members with the same names.

Those are not errors, just warnings. If you want to suppress them just add `new` keyword to your property declaration, but remember this also probably means you're doing something wrong because hiding members of a base class is rarely something you actually want to do. To understand this concept better you should read about inheritance in c#. [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) can be good place to start.

Comment: How do you handle it when it's automatically generated? Every time I regenerate my service reference, it replaces the `new` keyword. I was just thinking of suppressing the warning, but is there a better way?

Comment: @AlexKwitny you could just give those members different names to avoid hiding members of the base class, which is usually a better idea anyway. Hiding members makes code more confusing, harder to use and debug, because suddenly you have two separate members that have the same name.